Data missing from report populated for few column using grapecity.documents.gcExcel 7.2.1 version
I am using grapecity.document.gcExcel (7.2.1) and for few columns, data is not getting populated.
So I want to populate the data in column C, D, F, G, I, J but the data is getting populated in only columns F, G, I, J but not in column C and D.
The mapping for column C and D are --> {{dsFy0.assets.land.value}} (This data is for 1st FY)
The mapping for column F and G are --> {{dsFy1.assets.land.value}} (This data is for 2nd FY)
The mapping for column I and J are --> {{dsFy2.assets.land.value}} (This data is for 3rd FY)
The data map is for cell range C20:J30. Also the map value for cell C18 and C19 are {{dsFy.assets.buildings.value}}. Data is present for this cell
Why is the data not being populated for column C and D for rows 7-15.
This is the table that I am trying to populate and with the mapping.




Gross block
Depreciation
Net block
Gross block
Depreciation
Net block





in Rs.
in Rs.
in Rs.
in Rs.
in Rs.
in Rs.


(a) Land
{{dsFy0.assets.land.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.land.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.land.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.land.value}}
#VALUE!


(b) Buildings
{{dsFy0.assets.buildings.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.buildings.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.buildings.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.buildings.value}}
#VALUE!


(c) Plant and Equipment (Machinery)
{{dsFy0.assets.plantAndEquipment.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.plantAndEquipment.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.plantAndEquipment.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.plantAndEquipment.value}}
#VALUE!


(d) Furniture and Fixtures
{{dsFy0.assets.furnitureAndFixtures.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.furnitureAndFixtures.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.furnitureAndFixtures.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.furnitureAndFixtures.value}}
#VALUE!


(e) Vehicles
{{dsFy0.assets.vehicles.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.vehicles.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.vehicles.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.vehicles.value}}
#VALUE!


(f) Office equipment
{{dsFy0.assets.officeEquipment.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.officeEquipment.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.officeEquipment.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.officeEquipment.value}}
#VALUE!


(g) Leasehold improvements
{{dsFy0.assets.leaseholdImprovements.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.leaseholdImprovements.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.leaseholdImprovements.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.leaseholdImprovements.value}}
#VALUE!


(h) Computers
{{dsFy0.assets.computers.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.computers.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.computers.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.computers.value}}
#VALUE!


(i) Others
{{dsFy0.assets.others.value}}
{{dsFy0.assets.others.value}}
#VALUE!
{{dsFy1.assets.others.value}}
{{dsFy1.assets.others.value}}
#VALUE!



Here is the code to set the value for
    final Object newFyObject = sortedFys.get(0).getClass().newInstance();

    return WorkBookDetail.builder()
            .initDataSource(wb -> wb.addDataSource("dsFy", sortedFys))
            .initDataSource(wb -> wb.addDataSource("dsFy0", sortedFys.size()>0 ? sortedFys.get(0) : newFyObject))
            .initDataSource(wb -> wb.addDataSource("dsFy1", sortedFys.size()>1 ? sortedFys.get(1) : newFyObject))
            .build

And the bean for workbook detail is
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class WorkBookDetail {
    private Workbook workBook;
    private SheetMetaDetail sheetMetaDetail;
    @Singular
    private List<Consumer<Workbook>> initDataSources;
}

Also have there been any changes in the latest version for how the mapping is done as the changes were working for version 7.0.5.
